# How to use "where" and "whereBetween" on the same query

Tags: laravel-5

I want the two conditions to retrieve only data that match, that means the data should be in this range `->whereBetween('date_applied', [$start_date, $end_date])` but also they should meet the second condtion`->orwhere('req_id', $req_id[$i])`. Can anyone help me to align the two clauses together?

```
$did = DB::table('ssrareqs')->select('particular_id', 'quantity_req',
                'purpose', 'date_applied','date_approved', 'quantity_issued', 'remarks', 'status_issue', 'status_req')
                ->whereBetween('date_applied', [$start_date, $end_date])
                ->orwhere('req_id', $req_id[$i])
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested . Hope it works .Just remind that you have to use `use` :

```
     $did =DB::table('ssrareqs')->select('req_id','particular_id', 'quantity_req','purpose', 'date_applied','date_approved', 'quantity_issued', 'remarks', 'status_issue', 'status_req')
     ->where(function($query) use ($start_date, $end_date,$req_id[$i]){
     $query->whereBetween('date_applied',array($start_date,$start_date))
     ->orwhere('req_id', $req_id[$i]);
     })
     ->get();
```

Comment: add `req_id` select query .. i think your table('ssrareqs') have `req_id`

Comment: Still the same error, it says; syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ')'. It is between $end_date,$req_id[$i])

Comment: add ; at the end of that line